# Unable to locate the Filter box drupal view

Tags: filter, drupal-7, drupal-views

I am new to drupal and learning Drupal views currently. I have a problem, in my book it written that after cloning and enabling the "recent comments view" , clicking edit option will show `Filters` box. In my book it is written as

```
1. Click + link in the Filters box
2. A dialogue box titled Masters:Add filters will open 
etc.
```

Can you suggest me where the Filter is located or do I need to modify/add anything?

Answer (score 0):

hi use Filter criteria and add content type for filtering your data.